# Android: how to make own keyboard control

Tags: android

I have an edittext.when i type any key from keyboard, i want instead of that character some another character comes. for ex- if i type a, it should come b on edit text box. Please, any one tell me how to do this. I am implementing addTextChangedListener. But i don't understand this callback methods.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean but I try to figure it out:

You want that everytime you write a char in the editText the app writes the next letter (For example a->b, b->c, c->d,etc...etc...).

This method you should put it in the onTextChanged.
You should retrieve the ASCII value of the char you writes and then make it like this:

```
char c = 'a'; //The value of ´a´ in ASCII e´97
int i = (int) c; 
int i++;
```

So like this you have saved in i the ASCII value of ´b´.

How it works the method onTExtChanged you can have a look here--> http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/using-textwatcher-in-android.html

Comment: Which other meaning?The reason you should do something like that is only to hide the value of The string to Someone but there are a milion of other method instead of this...try to explain better and tell me if The solution worked.

Comment: Other meaning... giving own replacement character instead the real one... As my requirement i need to use editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() only....

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside `onTextChanged()`:

```
String str = editText.getText().toString();
if (str.length() == 0)
    return;
editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
switch (str.charAt(str.length() - 1)) {
    case 'a':
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) + 'b';
        editText.setText(str);
        editText.setSelection(str.length());
        break;
}
editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Comment: Each time if i press a, it doesn't change to b. Also if we type some text and then erase all, again we type a, it doesn't change...

Comment: Tried it just now, and it is working fine. Are you using uppercase 'A' instead?

Comment: Yea.. i got it... i didn't call editText.addTextChangedListener(this); previously... thank you ... But it is not good idea to use switch case for every character... Any other logic for all the alphabet letters...

Comment: That depends on what your replacement is. If there is the some order, you could use ASCII. But for random ones, you definitely need mapping of some kind.